# adding Auth and Acl components into custom framework with Composer

Tags: php, authorization, composer-php

I've developed my own PHP framework which is used to power many different apps. At the moment, it uses Twig, Symfony YAML, Monolog and Facebook SDK as components. Now I need to create an admin section so those who update the content can login to a secure area, and very likely a user section, so their would be different roles too.

I like the look of Zend and Symfony's components and I have found many Stack Overflow questions related to it, but I was wondering:

1. If I use Symfony2's Security Component, how do I use it outside of the Symfony2 framework? This is very frustratingly missing from the Components Handbook, seeing as they've documented every other of their components.
2. If I use Zend_Auth and Zend_Acl, can I load them with Composer, without downloading the full stack? Or would I have to download it manually and extract the classes?
3. Do you recommend another package?

Comment: You should consider ZF2 components instead of ZF1 ones. ZF2 components are easy to load with Composer.

Comment: 2. yes you can. You have to download and extract class.

Comment: @Florent am I right in thinking that zf-commons/zfc-acl or zf-commons/* are official packages for ZF2 components?

Comment: No you are wrong. Official ZF2 package is `zendframework/zendframework`. There no longer are `zendframework/*` packages.

Comment: @Florent Damn, that's annoying. I wonder why they did that, especially when their must be others like myself that need only 2 packages as opposed to adding 200MB to my project.

Comment: For you information, `zf-commons` packages load the entire ZF2 framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. http://packages.zendframework.com/

Reason I didn't find this out earlier, Zend 2 uses it's own repository instead of Packagist.

**Composer.json:**

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
    }
],
```

and

```
"require": {
    "zendframework/zend-authentication": "2.0.*",
    "zendframework/zend-permissions-acl": "2.0.*"
},

"minimum-stability": "beta"
```

Though I'm using `"minimum-stability": "dev"` for my project